# `plotly` Sankey plot: able to color the inflows and outflows upon hovering over a node

Tags: python, colors, graphics, plotly, sankey-diagram

I am working with the `plotly` package in Python and have made a nice Sankey plot. Other Stack Overflow posts discuss how to set the connection colors. However, I am content to have the default colors unless the user hovers over a node. In that case, I would like the inflows to light up in blue and the outflows to light up in red.

Does `plotly` support this? If so, what would be the syntax? If not, would another Python package support this form of interaction in a Sankey plot?